# Derive column name from date in rows and show monthly data in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below:

```
CREATE table #yourtable
(
    [Id] int, 
    [ColumnName] varchar(13), 
    Val1 float, 
    Val2 float, 
    StartDate datetime, 
    EndDate datetime
);

INSERT INTO #yourtable
    ([Id], [ColumnName],Val1,Val2,StartDate,EndDate)
VALUES
    (1,'ABC12',1000,900,'2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-01-31 23:59:59'),
    (2,'ABC12',1100,900,'2016-02-01 00:00:00','2016-02-29 23:59:59'),
    (3,'CDE34',1000,800,'2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-01-31 23:59:59'),
    (4,'EFG45',1000,700,'2016-03-01 00:00:00','2016-03-31 23:59:59'),
    (5,'FGH56',1000,1001,'2016-02-01 00:00:00','2016-02-29 23:59:59');
```

I am trying to get monthly segregated data like below:

```
Column Name Jan      Feb      Mar
    ABC12   1000     1100     null
    ABC12   900      900      null
    CDE34   1000     null     null
    CDE34   800      null     null
    EFG45   null     null     1000
    EFG45   null     null     700
    FGH56   null     1000     null
    FGH56   null     1001     null
```

I am relatively new to sql.
Thanks in advance

Comment: sql server or mysql?

Comment: Hi Denis, Sql server

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
SELECT  * FROM (SELECT  [ColumnName],
            SUM(Val1) AS _Val, 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(StartDate), - 1))) MonthCol
            FROM #yourtable WHERE YEAR(StartDate) = 2016
            GROUP BY  StartDate,[ColumnName]) AS TP
     PIVOT (SUM(_Val) FOR MonthCol IN ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec])) AS PVTTable
UNION
SELECT  * FROM (SELECT  [ColumnName],
            SUM(Val2) AS _Val, 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(EndDate), - 1))) MonthCol
            FROM #yourtable WHERE YEAR(EndDate) = 2016
            GROUP BY  EndDate,[ColumnName]) AS TP
     PIVOT (SUM(_Val) FOR MonthCol IN ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec])) AS PVTTable
```

For Dynamic Query

```
    DECLARE @MaxMonth DATE = GETDATE();
    DECLARE @YearData NVARCHAR(4) = CAST(YEAR(@MaxMonth) AS NVARCHAR(4))
    DECLARE @END_MM INT = MONTH(@MaxMonth) --End of Month
    DECLARE @START_MM INT = 1 --Start Month of Year Data

    DECLARE @TB_DATE AS TABLE
    (
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        MONTH_LIST VARCHAR(12)
    )
    WHILE @START_MM <= @END_MM
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @TB_DATE (MONTH_LIST) VALUES ('['+CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, @START_MM-1, CAST(@END_MM AS datetime))))+']')
        SET @START_MM=@START_MM+1
    END

    DECLARE @MM_LIST NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + MONTH_LIST 
                        FROM @TB_DATE ORDER BY ID DESC
                        FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') AS Txt)

    DECLARE @DynamicPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @DynamicPivot = N' SELECT  * FROM (SELECT  [ColumnName],
            SUM(Val1) AS _Val, 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(StartDate), - 1))) MonthCol
            FROM #yourtable WHERE YEAR(StartDate) = '+@YearData+'
            GROUP BY  StartDate,[ColumnName]) AS TP
     PIVOT (SUM(_Val) FOR MonthCol IN ('+@MM_LIST+')) AS PVTTable
     UNION
     SELECT  * FROM (SELECT  [ColumnName],
            SUM(Val2) AS _Val, 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(EndDate), - 1))) MonthCol
            FROM #yourtable WHERE YEAR(EndDate) = '+@YearData+'
            GROUP BY  EndDate,[ColumnName]) AS TP
     PIVOT (SUM(_Val) FOR MonthCol IN ('+@MM_LIST+')) AS PVTTable';

 EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivot
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. It was a great help.However, can i not set the number of months dynamically. Lets say,if the dates are from Jan to Aug, then is show rows from Jan to Aug dynamically. How do i integrate this logic with the above query. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes we can, Please try in Dynamic Query as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With [pivoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT  ColumnName,
        MAX([Jan]) as [Jan],
        MAX([Feb]) as [Feb],
        MAX([Mar]) as [Mar],
        MAX([Apr]) as [Apr],
        MAX([May]) as [May],
        MAX([Jun]) as [Jun],
        MAX([Jul]) as [Jul],
        MAX([Aug]) as [Aug]
FROM (
    SELECT  Id,
            ColumnName,
            LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,StartDate),3) as M,
            [Vals],
            [Column]
    FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM #yourtable) y
    UNPIVOT (
         [Column] FOR Vals IN ([Val1],[Val2])
    )as unpvt
    ) as s
PIVOT (
    MAX([Column]) FOR M IN ([Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Jul],[Aug])
) as pvt
GROUP BY ColumnName,Vals
ORDER BY ColumnName
```

Output:

```
ColumnName  Jan     Feb     Mar
ABC12       1000    1100    NULL
ABC12       900     900     NULL
CDE34       1000    NULL    NULL
CDE34       800     NULL    NULL
EFG45       NULL    NULL    1000
EFG45       NULL    NULL    700
FGH56       NULL    1000    NULL
FGH56       NULL    1001    NULL
```

With [UNPIVOT](http://www.tsqltutorials.com/unpivot.php) we get this table structure:

```
Id  ColumnName  M   Vals    Column
1   ABC12       Jan Val1    1000
1   ABC12       Jan Val2    900
2   ABC12       Feb Val1    1100
2   ABC12       Feb Val2    900
3   CDE34       Jan Val1    1000
3   CDE34       Jan Val2    800
4   EFG45       Mar Val1    1000
4   EFG45       Mar Val2    700
5   FGH56       Feb Val1    1000
5   FGH56       Feb Val2    1001
```

So all `Vals` are in one column, then we use [PIVOT](http://www.tsqltutorials.com/pivot.php) to get desired result with the help of [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) and [ORDER BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx).

If there are many `Vals` better use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is exactly what i wanted. However, can i not set the number of months dynamically. Lets say,if the dates are from Jan to Aug, then is show rows from Jan to Aug dynamically. How do i integrate this logic with the above query. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just add month you need in the pivot and max expression from the top of query.

Comment: There are only 12 month so I guess it is better to avoid dynamic SQL in this particular situation. I add another month to my answer.